# Why does my ESP32 suffer from wifi stuttering when is next to wifi USB dongle?

Tags: electromagnetism, wifi

I have an ESP32 connected to Wi-Fi 2.4GHz. It is positioned next to my PC's Wi-Fi USB dongle, which is connected to the same network at 5GHz. When the PC is on (the USB dongle is active), my ESP32 disconnects and reconnects from the Wi-Fi every 15–60 seconds on average. Why does this happen if they are at different GHz ranges?
[image]

Comment: induced currents in some part of the circuit could be causing this ... the problem could also be caused by something else

Comment: I'm a complete layman regarding electromagnetic interference but I once had a similar issue with a 2.4GHz wifi dongle and a PIR sensor. The PIR sensor triggered whenever the wifi dongle transmitted data. I solved it by creating a simple shielding between these two components using some cardboard and tinfoil.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a well-known issue with signal interference between WiFi and USB3. In fact, the main peak of energy of 5Gbps USB3 signal is centered at Nyquist frequency of 2.5 GHz, not 5GHz, which is quite close to 2.4. When USB link transmits data in active state, the spectrum of signals looks like this (one of USB3 pattern, USB3 specifications 1.1 page 90):

[image]

Obviously the signal is supposed to be totally differential, and shielded twisted pairs should not emit much, but nothing is perfect, and USB3 cable connectors, cables and enclosures do emit parasitic sidebands. When in close proximity, USB3 interferes with WiFi, [this article provides detailed explanation](https://www.usb.org/sites/default/files/327216.pdf).

Answer (score 3):

> Why does this happen if they are at different GHz ranges?

The boards are *meant* to be working at different bands. That's the design *intent*. Obviously, the *execution* - how well the manufacturers did their job - is a bit lacking.

It may happen because at least one of the boards - whether the ESP32 board or the USB dongle - has poor electromagnetic compatibility. Devices that are WiFi certified should have no problems like that. They are tested for precisely these scenarios during [plugfests/plugtests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plugtest).

It is possible that the dongle wasn't certified and suffers from poor design. It's also worth checking if the ESP32 module and the carrier it's on are designed correctly and had certification testing done to the extent that subassemblies are tested (vs. finished systems).

Comment: Very interesting, I didn't know about plugtests and the importance of Wi-Fi certification.  So, probably there are 2.4 GHZ signals that are leaking from the Wi-Fi USB dongle and are interfering with the ESP32, making it hard to connect, isn't it?